# Facebook like button renders beyond screen canvas

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm having a issue with Facebook Like Button. When I click **Like**, the iframe is being rendered outside of the screen size, see by yourself:

## Before clicking Like

[image: Facebook before like]

## After clicking Like

[image: Facebook after like]

I use the default like button code, provided by Facebook

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="https://facebook.com/loremipsum" data-width="500" 
data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="false">
```